# Seaborn: Plot scatterplot over lineplot in same plot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to create one plot with one scatter and multiple lineplots.
For the points to be seen well, I need the scatterplot in the front.
However changing the order inside my code doesn't solve this. The
lineplots always cover the scatterplot. Any ideas?

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `zorder` parameter when scatterplotting, e.g.

```
sns.scatterplot(x, y, ax=ax, color='orange', zorder=7)
```

You may need to adjust the `zorder` value depending on the number of elements in your plot.